# Можно ли соеденить Android TV с ноутбуком сетью Linux

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

Есть Телевизор с приставкой с android TV. Есть ноут с ОС Ubuntu 18.04. Можно   ли зайти под одного из пользователей на Android TV.

Comment: По ssh? Можно .

Comment: @TotalPusher по идее, можно еще коннкетиться с помощью Miraclecast.

Comment: Непонятно откуда куда зайти хотите? С Андроида или с Убунты?